# No puedo insertar utilizando este código php

Tags: php, html, sql-server

```
<?php 
include("../conexion.php");
    if (isset($_POST['estado_emisor']) && !empty($_POST['estado_emisor']) 
        && isset($_POST['emisor']) && !empty($_POST['emisor'])
        && isset($_POST['dnombre']) && !empty($_POST['dnombre']) 
        && isset($_POST['dpaterno']) && !empty($_POST['dpaterno'])
        && isset($_POST['dmaterno']) && !empty($_POST['dmaterno']))  
    {
        if (!$con)
        {
          die (" No se puede usar la base de datos " . sqlsrv_error($con));
        }
        else 
        { 
            $query=sqlsrv_query($con,"INSERT INTO nombres(ESTADO_EMISOR,EMISOR,DNOMBRE,DPATERNO,DMATERNO) VALUES('$estado_emisor','$emisor','$dnombre','$dpaterno','$dmaterno')");

            echo'<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Datos incerdados");
        window.location.href="../index.php";
        </script>';
        }
            }
     else 
     {
         echo'<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Error al incertar los datos");
        window.location.href="../index.php";
        </script>'; 
     }
?>
```

Comment: Tienes algun error?

Comment: Si, no me inserta los datos en la tabla "nombres". No me marca error de sintaxis pero no hace la funcion

Comment: ¿Te aparece el alert("Datos incerdados");? Si no, ¿Te aparece esto: No se puede usar la base de datos... ?

Comment: No veo donde le das valor a las variables `$estado_emisor`, `$emisor`, ... etc.

Comment: Añade al último  } un else con un var_dump de las variables pasadas, así podrás ver los valores, pues parece que no los hay y no entra en el if. Sería así: } else { var_dump($_REQUEST); }

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Seria mas facil si mostraras el error que te da, primero verifica si el archivo de conexion esta correcto con nombre, pass de bd y ademas en la locacion que comentas.
despues puedes verificar si los campos a insertar son tal y como estan escritos tambien en la bd de datos.